# lumen order by with two level relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

this is a task manager web app

i have 3 tables `rows`, `tasks` and `inputs`

the `inputs` table has `order` column to choice which column to be shown first

`row` has many `tasks`

`input` has many `tasks`

so every `task` has an `input` and a `row`

i want to sort the tasks by `row_id` and then by `input.order`

first try

```
App\Row::with(['user', 'tasks', 'tasks.option', 'tasks.input'])
  ->orderBy('rows.id', 'ASC', 'order', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

it ignores the order

result

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:23",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:23",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 1,
                "option_id": 1,
                "value": null,
                "input": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "assigned to",
                    "type": 1,
                    "value": "mario",
                    "required": 1,
                    "order": 2,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:16",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 2,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "test new option",
                "input": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test new option",
                    "type": 0,
                    "value": "test new option",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 3,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:44",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 3,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "2018-07-01",
                "input": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "deadline",
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": "2018-07-01",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 4,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:07:37",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 4,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "",
                "input": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "priority",
                    "type": 6,
                    "value": "",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

second try

```
App\Row::with(['user', 'tasks', 'tasks.option', 'tasks.input'])
  ->orderBy('rows.id', 'ASC')
  ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

but it generated an error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `rows` order by `rows`.`id` asc, `order` asc)
```

third try

```
App\Row::with([
  'user', 
  'tasks', 
  'tasks.option', 
  'tasks.input' => 
    function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
    }
  ])
  ->orderBy('rows.id', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

it ignores the order result same as first

forth try

```
    return App\Row::with(['user', 'tasks', 'tasks.option', 'tasks.input'])
        ->join('tasks', 'rows.id', '=', 'tasks.row_id')
        ->join('inputs', 'inputs.id', '=', 'tasks.input_id')
        ->orderBy('rows.id', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy( 'inputs.order', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

it generate row for every column and not row as it suppose to

result

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
        "row_id": 1,
        "input_id": 4,
        "option_id": null,
        "value": "",
        "name": "priority",
        "type": 6,
        "required": 0,
        "order": 1,
        "tasks": []
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:16",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
        "row_id": 1,
        "input_id": 1,
        "option_id": 1,
        "value": "mario",
        "name": "assigned to",
        "type": 1,
        "required": 1,
        "order": 2,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 1,
                "option_id": 1,
                "value": null,
                "input": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "assigned to",
                    "type": 1,
                    "value": "mario",
                    "required": 1,
                    "order": 2,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:16",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 2,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "test new option",
                "input": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test new option",
                    "type": 0,
                    "value": "test new option",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 3,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:44",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 3,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "2018-07-01",
                "input": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "deadline",
                    "type": 3,
                    "value": "2018-07-01",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 4,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:07:37",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "row_id": 1,
                "input_id": 4,
                "option_id": null,
                "value": "",
                "input": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "priority",
                    "type": 6,
                    "value": "",
                    "required": 0,
                    "order": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-06-07 18:40:44",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
        "row_id": 1,
        "input_id": 2,
        "option_id": null,
        "value": "test new option",
        "name": "test new option",
        "type": 0,
        "required": 0,
        "order": 3,
        "tasks": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-06-08 10:07:37",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-08 10:08:19",
        "row_id": 1,
        "input_id": 3,
        "option_id": null,
        "value": "2018-07-01",
        "name": "deadline",
        "type": 3,
        "required": 0,
        "order": 4,
        "tasks": []
    }
]
```

this file is [here](https://github.com/robertIsaac/task-manager/blob/master/lumen/app/Http/Controllers/Task.php)

the full code is [here](https://github.com/robertIsaac/task-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Because it searches columns in table `rows` not in `input`.

```
  App\Row::with(['user', 'tasks', 'tasks.option', 'tasks.input'=> function ($q){
        $q->orderBy('order', 'ASC'); // order from "rows" table
    }])
  ->orderBy('id', 'ASC') // id from "rows" table
  ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'input.order' in 'order clause'

Comment: in which table you have column `order` ?

Comment: `inputs`.`order`

Comment: it ignores the order, how is it any different from the third try?

Comment: Are you checking at `$result =  App\Row::` as `$result->tasks` ? or `$result->tasks->input` ?

Comment: `$result->tasks`

Comment: but that doesn't matter actually, cause the task value and input is paired

Comment: if you change order type for `->orderBy('id', 'DESC')` then it would reverting order right ?

Comment: it has no affect at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172758/discussion-between-robert-and-c2486).